# Excel: Nested IF statement to check 3 conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested-if

I have an excel sheet with a column representing time in hours. I need to insert an if statement next to each cell to check the following:

1. Values less than 24 hours
2. Values more than 24 hours and less than 48 hours
3. Values greater than 48 hours

I am able to successfully query for two cases; less than 24 hours and greater than 48 hours. However, my nested `IF` statement is unable to fetch for the condition where value is more than 24 hours and less than 48 hours. Please help

```
IF(Q14<=TIME(23,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1), "24", IF(AND(Q14>TIME(23,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1), Q14<TIME(47,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1)),"48", IF(Q14>TIME(48,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1), "96", "Poor ")))
```

Comment: what is the format of the cells in `Q14` ? is it a `Number` or `Time` (like `hh:mm:ss`) ? what is the value entered inside this cell (before the conversion) ?

Comment: The value is a calculation of StartTime - EndTime in the format [h]:mm:ss. My values include 44:54:41, 68:08:44 etc. My nested if statement works for "24 hours" and "96 hours" but does not work for "48 hours"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'HOUR' function to check:

```
IF(HOUR(Q14) < 24, "under 24", IF(HOUR(Q14) < 48, "24 - 48", "over 48"))
```

In Excel IF () Function, if you write like this:

```
IF(HOUR(Q14) < 24, "under 24", ...second case...)
```

in second case it's true that HOUR(Q14) >= 24, so you don't have to check HOUR(Q14) >= 24 again.

**Update**

Because in excel you can't input hour > 24. Following your input, If you  minus `EndTime-StartTime` then the real value of the cell is actually number of day. So you can multiply 24 to the value of the cell to get the total hour, following formula:

```
IF(24 * Q14 < 24, "under 24", IF(24 * Q14 < 48, "under 48", "over 48"))
```

That's easy. Happy coding!

Comment: I removed the check for the second case modified as `IF(Q13<=TIME(23,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1), "24", IF(Q13<TIME(47,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1),"48", IF(Q13>TIME(48,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1), "96", "Poor ")))` but it still skips the second case

Comment: Because TIME(47, 59, 59) + TIME(0, 0, 1) returns 10:00 PM. So in excel you can't input time > 24:00:00.

Comment: okay, so back to my question how do I query based on my question above since i want to query based on the hour values I have as 24, 48 etc